# Helper String concatenation / Find current Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, helper, string-concatenation

I'm trying to get the current controller for an Error Notification.

**helper.rb**

```
  def error_message_for(field, options = {:prepend_text => "#{'<i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i> '}"}, controller = {:current => "@" + params[:controller] })
    error_message = controller[:current].errors[field][0]
    if error_message
      raw "#{options[:prepend_text]} #{error_message}"
    end
  end
```

But I'm getting a `NoMethodError` `undefined method`errors' for "@screens":String`

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`errors` method is accessible on `ActiveRecord::Base` objects i.e., in your case on instances of your model(Screen)  which extend `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Currently you receive error as `NoMethodError undefined method errors for "@screens":String`
because you are not invoking `errors` method on a `String` ("@screens") instead of an instance of your model. `"@screens"` is a String formed by concatenating `"@" + params[:controller]`, it is NOT an instance variable `@screens`.

So, you would need to pass an instance of your model class to your `error_message_for` method and then call `errors` on it.

**For example:**

```
  def error_message_for(object, field, options = {:prepend_text => "#{'<i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i> '}"}})
    error_message = object.errors[field][0]
    if error_message
      raw "#{options[:prepend_text]} #{error_message}"
    end
  end
```

**Call it as below:**

```
<%= form_for(@screen) do |f| %>
  <%= error_message_for(@screen,:field_name) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you apply this on the code i provided so i can look at it, i'm not so sure how to do this.

Comment: Oh, if i understood correctly you mean to pass the controller in the view? I'm trying to understand this (Newbie here). Currently i'm getting a `wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the error message for a field in a form you can get it by doing something like this:

```
<%= form_for(@screen) do |f| %>
  <%= f.object.errors.get(:field_name) %>
<% end %>
```

Or with a helper

```
# in view
<%= error_message_for(f, :field_name) %>

# in helper
def error_message_for(form_object, field_name, ...)
  error_messages = form_object.object.errors.get(field_name)
  if error_messages.present?
    raw "#{...} #{error_messages.first}"
  end
end
```

Benefit of this solution is that you do not need to pass around the object (`@screen`) itself what makes it easier to use this code with nested forms.

Comment: That's also a way, but in my view it's much clearer with the helper because i add a lot of stuff to the errors.